# DATETIME convert

Tags: java, sms, datetime-format

can anyone help me with converting DATETIME funtction in Java.
I retrieve the date time format from SMS headers in this format "Fri May 18 09:22:39 FJT 2012" .I want to convert it to this format "2012-05-18 09:51:42.39".Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for that purpose. Although I am not sure that the timezone "FJT" is known in Java. So you will maybe have to do some tricks for that.

Answer (score 0):

As @Guillaume suggested, use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Here's an example:

```
public String convert() throws ParseException  { 
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Date output =  format.parse("Fri May 18 09:22:39 FJT 2012");
    Calendar outputCal = Calendar.getInstance(format.getTimeZone());
    outputCal.setTime(output);
    return String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",outputCal.get(Calendar.YEAR),     outputCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,  outputCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), outputCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), outputCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), outputCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
}
```

Everything is hardcoded - you have to add parameters as necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

...

```
String d = "Fri May 18 09:22:39 FJT 2012";
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SS");
outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));  // set yr time zone for output
Date date = inputFormat.parse(d);
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: The problem with this is - it will output the date in *your* timezone not FJT :).

Comment: Since the question has two different values for the time, I wasn't sure that that wasn't the intention, but I should have made it explicit - thanks, Chip!